# Iterating in Scala: checking previous values

Tags: scala, iterator, tuples

I am having the following iterator:

```
val it = Iterator(("a",5),("a",3),("a",2),("a",1),("b",8),("b",2),("b",1),("c",1))
```

The values inside are sorted firstly by the first element(String) and secondly by the second(Int). How can I get the first 2 values from each 'letter'. So the result should be in that example:

```
Iterator(("a",5),("a",3),("b",8),("b",2),("c",1))
```

It can be done with groupBy:

```
it.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.take(2)).values.flatten.toIterator
```

but I would like to see a solution which goes through each element and check the previous 'string' element and if its the same and the 'count' is less than 2 then it `yield` this value.

**Edit**:

Following the logic of @jwvh answer: How can it be generalized to take the first N values instead of the first 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be nice if we didn't have to consume the entire iterator all at once.

**UPDATED**

```
case class LimitItr[A,B](var itr: Iterator[(A,B)], reps:Int) extends Iterator[(A,B)] {
  private var memory: List[A] = List()
  def hasNext = itr.hasNext
  def next() = {
    val current = itr.next
    if (!memory.headOption.contains(current._1))
      memory = List()
    memory = current._1 :: memory
    if (memory.length >= reps) {
      itr = itr.dropWhile(_._1 == memory.head)
      itr.hasNext  // force the iterator forward
    }
    current
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val repLimitedItr = LimitItr(itrOfTuples, numOfRepetitionsAllowed)
```

Comment: thanks! I tried to `yield` the results in a `while` loop: `while(lit.hasNext()) { yield lit.next() }` but it doesnt work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: or is this `for (elem <- lit) yield elem` considered a good practice?

Comment: My apologies for the comments. how could this be generalized to N first values instead of the first 2?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `for (e <- lit) yield e` will get you the same thing as what you started with: a non-empty `Iterator[(String,Int])`.  If you do `LimitItr(it).toList` you'll consume the iterator and you might as well go with one of the `foldLeft` solutions.  If you do `LimitItr(it).toSeq` or `.toStream` you'll get a lazy evaluated `Stream` that can be indexed, so that might be useful.

Comment: No, this cannot easily be generalized to keeping N first elements.  That would take some reworking.

Comment: I am gonna use this function as input of `mapPartition` in spark. So i am guessing the `for` method is what I want as it returns an Iterator.

Comment: But you've already got an iterator.  What does the `for` method get you?

Comment: You are right. My apologies but i am not familiar with Scala at all. Could the answer updated to N first elements?

Comment: I'll think on it, and see what I can come up with, but not right away.  Other things to do.  Maybe later today.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris, see if this fits the bill.

Comment: Final question : Why did u chouse to write `case class LimitItr[A,B](var itr: Iterator[(A,B)], reps:Int) extends Iterator[(A,B)]` instead of `case class LimitItr(var itr: Iterator[(String,Int)], reps:Int) extends Iterator[(String,Int)]` ? (my apologies if i am annoying)

Comment: @MpizosDimitris, I chose to use type parameters (the `[A,B]` notation) in order to make the code more general. It can now be used on an iterator of any 2-tuple type: `(Int,Char)` or `(Short,String)` or `(Boolean,Long)` etc. Also, your proposed edit (`toList`) is unnecessary.

Comment: Got it. As for the `toList`: for a reason that I dont know it was giving me an error. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `fold` operation, but it is more cumbersome than your solution:

```scala
val result = it.foldLeft((Seq[(String, Int)](), "", 0)){
  case ((acc, prev, count), (l, n)) =>
    if (prev == l) {
      if (count < 2) (acc :+ (l, n), prev, count + 1)
      else (acc, prev, count + 1)
    }
    else (acc :+ (l, n), l, 1)
}

println(result._1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using foldLeft could be:

```
it.foldLeft (List[(String, Int)]()) {
  case (acc, (k,v)) if acc.takeWhile(_._1==k).size<2 => (k,v)::acc
  case (acc, _) => acc
}.reverse
```

Comment: Cool one! Is there way of using `yield` in your answer, instead of 'storing' it to a final result?